# Can I breakup the code to executing the .Find method?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to break up this line of code, to make it more digestible, in smaller steps, but I am running in problems that I either get compile errors, run time errors, or just plain the wrong response.

As a beginner in coding of VBA, maybe somebody enlightens me, why it is not possible, or if it is possible where I am going wrong with my approach.

This code is functional snippet is below, but the function following is not

```
Dim WksN As String
Dim res As Object
' Set res = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:=name
Set res = Sheets(WksN).Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:=name _
                        , LookIn:=xlValues _
                        , LookAt:=xlPart _
                        , SearchOrder:=xlByColumns _
                        , SearchDirection:=xlPrevious _
                        , MatchCase:=False)

Public Function GetColumnNumber(ByVal WksN As String, _
                                ByVal name As String) As Long
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim res As Object
    Dim clmn As Object

    ' Set wks = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(CStr(WksN))
    ' Set wks = Sheets(CStr(WksN))
    ' Set wks = Sheets(CStr(WksN)).Activate
    ' Set wks = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(CStr(WksN)).Activate

    Set wks = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(CStr(WksN))     '
    ' Set rng = wks.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Select          ' Run time error

    ' Set rng = wks.Activate                    ' Not needed ??
   ' Set rng = wks.Rows(1).Select                ' Compile error
    Set rng = wks.Rows(1)

    ' With wks.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow            ' Didn't work
    With rng
        Set clmn = .Find(What:=name, _
                         LookIn:=xlValues, _
                         LookAt:=xlPart, _
                         SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                         SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                         MatchCase:=False)
   End With

   If res Is Nothing Then
        GetColumnNumber = 0
    Else
        GetColumnNumber = clmn.Column
   End If
End Function
```

I would like to set the range of the entire first row and then
search and find the column in which my string is stored.

I am not sure if the statement from above is atomic and can't be broken up,
or how I am not activating or selecting the "right" range, as the return value of this function is zero when the return value of the first code snippet is none zero and correct. 
The second question I have that I seem not to select the range when I am using the .Rows(1) statement, which strikes me that I must fundamentally not understand how this is supposed to work.

Comment: You are setting `res` outside of your function so that it will never instantiate that variable and will always be nothing when you check. Also should you not check `clm` as this is where you are doing a search inside your function?

Answer (score 1):

```
Set rng = wks.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Select  ' Run time error
```

`Select` does not return a value, so don't use that if you're trying to get a reference to a range

```
Set rng = wks.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow
```

This should work:

```
Public Function GetColumnNumber(ByVal WksN As String, _
                                ByVal hdr As String) As Long
    Dim f As Range

    Set f = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(WksN).Rows(1).Find( _
                    what:=hdr, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)

    If f Is Nothing Then
        GetColumnNumber = 0
    Else
        GetColumnNumber = f.Column
    End If
End Function
```